# Change + ordered to + leading

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying try to find the most selective criteria to start joining in SQL.

I tried this:

```
SELECT /*+ ordered */ 
  r3.object_id
FROM nc_references src
    INNER JOIN nc_objects     o ON o.object_type_id = 9146598858613093106
                               AND o.object_class_id = 90000330 
                               AND src.object_id = o.object_id
                               AND src.reference = 9155224548713314821
                               AND src.attr_id = 90100080 
    INNER JOIN nc_params      p ON ( p.list_value_id = 90100071  OR p.list_value_id = 90100072 )
                              AND p.object_id = o.object_id
                              AND p.attr_id = 90100070 
    INNER JOIN nc_po_actions  poa ON poa.manual_task_id = o.object_id
    INNER JOIN nc_po_tasks    pot ON pot.task_id = poa.task_id
    INNER JOIN nc_references  r1 ON r1.object_id = pot.container_id
                                   AND r1.attr_id = 9145923960313063683 
    INNER JOIN nc_references  r2 ON r2.object_id = pot.container_id
                                   AND r2.attr_id = 9145685312013687931 
    INNER JOIN nc_references  r3 ON r2.reference = r3.object_id
                                   AND r3.attr_id = 9145065302013613216 
                                   AND r1.reference = r3.reference
                     ;
```

But this `+ ordered` is deprecated. How I can implement this query using `+ leading`?

Comment: Have you tried without the hint?  The Oracle optimizer might do the right thing.

Comment: Yes, but the data is huge and the the execution is around 50 seconds.

Comment: Maybe 50 seconds is the best Oracle can do? Or do you have an indication that the database is optimizing inefficiently?

Comment: I don't have access to this data. Can you show me example with `+ leading` please?

Comment: You put the table aliases inside the leading() hint, in the order you want the database to join them. For example: `select /*+ leading(o p poa) */ from ...` would tell the database to start the query with o, THEN join p, THEN join poa.

Comment: ok, can you paste this as a complete answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the leading hint and put the table aliases between parentheses in the order you want the database to join them, for example:

```
SELECT /*+ leading(src o p poa) */ 
  r3.object_id
FROM nc_references src
INNER JOIN nc_objects     o ON o.object_type_id = 9146598858613093106
                           AND o.object_class_id = 90000330 
                           AND src.object_id = o.object_id
                           AND src.reference = 9155224548713314821
                           AND src.attr_id = 90100080 
INNER JOIN nc_params      p ON ( p.list_value_id = 90100071  OR p.list_value_id = 90100072 )
                          AND p.object_id = o.object_id
                          AND p.attr_id = 90100070 
INNER JOIN nc_po_actions  poa ON poa.manual_task_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN nc_po_tasks    pot ON pot.task_id = poa.task_id
INNER JOIN nc_references  r1 ON r1.object_id = pot.container_id
                               AND r1.attr_id = 9145923960313063683 
INNER JOIN nc_references  r2 ON r2.object_id = pot.container_id
                               AND r2.attr_id = 9145685312013687931 
INNER JOIN nc_references  r3 ON r2.reference = r3.object_id
                               AND r3.attr_id = 9145065302013613216 
                               AND r1.reference = r3.reference
                 ;
```

This would tell the database to start with src (nc_references), then o (nc_objects), etc.